Failed to load program into HAL component
I'm getting this error message when I execute my qiskit code on one of the available quantum computers of IBM:
qiskit_ibm_runtime.exceptions.RuntimeJobFailureError: 
'Unable to retrieve job result. Failed to load program into HAL component'

As additional information I'm trying to run my program in the quantum computer ibm_brisbane. The program uses 46 qubits.
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel='ibm_quantum')
provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.backends(name="ibm_brisbane")[0]
session = Session(service=service, backend="ibm_brisbane")

transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend=backend)
result = Sampler(session=session).run(transpiled_circuit, shots=number_shots).result().quasi_dists[0]

It does transpile the circuit, but when running, it gives back the error.
